# SoundCloud playlist in track info

Tags: soundcloud

I'm using the latest iteration of SoundCloud API and I need to fetch the latest 10 tracks I've uploaded on my various playlists.
Pretty simple stuff using the endpoint

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/users/[user-id]/tracks?limit=10
```

as you can see in their swagger docs: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/explorer/open-api

The problem is within the collection of track itself: there is no reference to the containing playlist(s) on each track (or anywhere whatsoever).

Any idea how to get this information?